# Elasticsearch is not working after full disk

Tags: elasticsearch

I made space, restarted the service (no good) and then rebooted but I still get this in the elasticsearch.log:

```
[2015-02-16 13:35:19,625][WARN ][cluster.action.shard     ] [Server] [logstash-2015.02.16][1] sending failed shard for [logstash-2015.02.16][1], node[PFamB-ZJS7CwSdyyAcP_8A], [P], s[INITIALIZING], indexUUID [tZ3I9HZ6TDaZSicIuGWRWQ], 
    reason [Failed to start shard, message [IndexShardGatewayRecoveryException[[logstash-2015.02.16][1] 
    failed to recover shard]; nested: TranslogCorruptedException[translog corruption while reading from stream]; nested: ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[No version type match [83]]; ]]
[2015-02-16 13:35:19,625][WARN ][cluster.action.shard     ] [Server] [logstash-2015.02.16][1] received shard failed for [logstash-2015.02.16][1], node[PFamB-ZJS7CwSdyyAcP_8A], [P], s[INITIALIZING], indexUUID [tZ3I9HZ6TDaZSicIuGWRWQ], 
    reason [Failed to start shard, message [IndexShardGatewayRecoveryException[[logstash-2015.02.16][1] 
    failed to recover shard]; nested: TranslogCorruptedException[translog corruption while reading from stream]; nested: ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[No version type match [83]]; ]]
[2015-02-16 13:35:43,570][DEBUG][action.index             ] [Server] observer: timeout notification from cluster service. timeout setting [1m], time since start [1m]
[2015-02-16 13:36:10,757][DEBUG][action.index             ] [Server] observer: timeout notification from cluster service. timeout setting [1m], time since start [1m]
```

What should I do?

Comment: is it a primary or a replica that has the issue?  what does `curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/_cat/shards?v"` show?

Comment: I got it fixed by moving out of the way the 
/var/lib/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/nodes/0/indices/logstash-2015.02.16/1/translog/translog-1424037601837.recovering
but I recon I now lost some events as this file was 40M?

Comment: Had the same issue after full disc. Moving the .recovery file out of the node's translog directory worked for me, but I have not done any analysis on if there was any dataloss.

Answer (score 6):

Bigfoot's solution is the only one that seems to work.

While the stack trace observed seems to be similar to: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/12055

This pull request is supposed to fix the issue: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/9797

But upgrading to v1.5.0 also does *not* do the trick.

Thus the only thing that works:

```
find  /var/lib/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/nodes/ -name "*.recovering"
```

And delete all recovering files.
Of course this has side-effects.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem too, with "No version type match" error in logs.

(Also, after disk got full)

Tried bigfoot's solution to manually delete recovery files and it worked.

Probably this can have some negative side effects though.